Using setAttributeNS for changing SVG Path Arc element
I'm trying to store the coordinates of my SVG Path statement inside the eXist database.  Here is my XHTML code:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
         <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
          <script language = "javascript" src = "http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.js">
          
          </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <input type = "text" id = "My_Text" value = "I was here."></input>
         <input type = "button" onclick = "Setup2()"/>
         <p id = "My_Paragraph"></p>
         <svg id = "My_SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500" width="500">
         <path id = "Bezier_Curve_1"/>
         <path id="Bezier_Curve_2" d="M 300, 200 A 50, 50 0,0,1 400,200" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
</path>
    </svg>
    </body>
</html>

Here is my Javascript code:
function Setup2() {
    var SVG_Def;
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    var Attribute_Name;
    var coordinate;
    
    document.getElementById("My_Text").value = "I'm right here.";
    SVG_Def = document.getElementById("My_SVG");
    Bezier_Curve_Identification = SVG.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttributeNS = ("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "'d'", "'M 300, 200 A 20, 20 0,0,1 340,200'");
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttributeNS = ("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "'style'", "'stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3; fill: none;'");
              }

When I click the button, the text in the textbox changes, but the arc on the screen does not change.  What am I doing wrong?
By the way, if I can store the attribute values inside these variables, then I can write an XQuery code to store the attribute values inside the eXist database.

Just use the regular (not-namespaced) method setAttribute() like so Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute("d","M 300, 200 A 20, 20 0,0,1 340,200");. You're currently applying it like a element property. Besides you need to remove the inner enclosing quotes.

If you want to use setAttributeNS use null fot the namespace: setAttributeNS(null,"d", "M 300 200 A 20 20 0 0 1 340 200");

You write to a variable SVG_Def, but read from an undefined SVG.

In this situation you don't need to use setAttributeNS, you can just use setAttribute.


function Setup2() {
  document.getElementById("My_Text").value = "I'm right here.";
  let Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
  Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute("d", "M 300 200 A 20 20 0 0 1 340 200");
  Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute("style", "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 10; fill: none;");
}
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="My_Text" value="I was here."/>
  <input type="button" onclick="Setup2()" value="Click" />
  <p id="My_Paragraph"></p>
  <svg id="My_SVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500" width="500">
    <path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
    <path id="Bezier_Curve_2" d="M 300 200 A 50, 50 0 0 1 400 200" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="none" />
  </svg>
</body>

</html>




I wasn't aware of the let command.  I will give this a try.  Now that I know that my curve will appear when I click the button, I can create an XML document.  It's in this document that I will store the Bezier curve coordinates.  That way if I ever want to change the coordinates, I don't have to search through an XHTML document.  Instead, I can search through an organized XML document and simply change the numbers.  Or I could just write a simple XQuery code and replace the numbers in the XML document.  This would work well with precision SVG animations.
